# What does "ldconfig deferred processing now taking place" mean?

Tags: apt

When I run `apt-get` with an option that installs packages, such as `apt-get install firefox` or `apt-get dist-upgrade`, the last line of output that I see is usually `ldconfig deferred processing now taking place`.  What is going on here?  What is `ldconfig`, and what does it do?

Answer (score 3):

ldconfig creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories (/lib and /usr/lib). The cache is used by the run-time linker, ld.so or ld-linux.so. ldconfig checks the header and filenames of the libraries it encounters when determining which versions should have their links updated.

ldconfig will attempt to deduce the type of ELF libs (i.e., libc5 or libc6/glibc) based on what C libs, if any, the library was linked against.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig

Comment: Please don't just cite the manpages, as they are often designed for developers or power users and not often suitable for the masses.  Instead, use your own terms to describe what (in this case) `ldconfig` is and how it works.

Comment: Agreeing with InkBlend - I search Google without even looking at man pages because they only make sense to people who already understand how Linux works. What is a linker?